# I am using the three tables like users, service_provider_category, category. How can I receive the data of category table

Tags: laravel

The relation of users.id = service_provider_category.user_id and service_provider_category.category_id = category.id

Answer (score 0):

Yes

Assuming that you have 3 models: User, ServiceProviderCategory and Category.

You need to create the relation ServiceProviderCategory in the User Model and create another relation of Category in the ServiceProvider Model.

Then you can easily access the data of the Category table using the eloquent relations.

```
$user = User::where('conditions')->with(['ServiceProviderCategory.Category'])->first();
```

and get Category table data as below

```
$categoryData = $user->ServiceProviderCategory->Category;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, assuming that you want to show the category data in `service_provider_category` and assuming you're using Eloquent.

```
ServiceProviderCategory::with('category')->get();
```

This will show the `category` data if there's an existing otherwise `null` if none.